# Why my result in this simple math problem in c++ is zero? Is there a technic problem. I am a beginner in programming

Tags: c++, math

```
#include <iostream>; 
using namespace std; 
 
int main() 
{ 

int a, b; 

cout << "please inter number \n"; 

cin >> a ;

cout << "please inter  number \n";
 
cin >> b ;

cout << "********\n" ;

float pi = 3.14 ;

float area = (pi*b*b/4) * ((2*a-b) / (2*a+b));

    cout << area << endl; 

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: what is the input? What is expected output?

Comment: `(2*a-b) / (2*a+b)` is using integer arithmetics

Comment: why are `a` and `b` not `float` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number make that an answer.

Comment: not a programming problem

Comment: The input for a and be is a=20, b=10

Comment: @MahammadQasm -- *The input for a and be is a=20, b=10* -- But `a` and `b` are not `float`.  Why did you make them `int`?  It also makes more sense to make them `float` anyway, as why should the input not also be fractional, i.e. `2.3` or `5.9`?

Comment: 463035818_is_not_a_number. Thanks the problem was using int instead of float in  for a & b.